# Configure IPsec only VPN on routerOS

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik

For connections from my iPhone into my home network when I'm outside, I configured a VPN based on L2TP and IPsec. I found a lot of examples in the internet for this configuration. All network traffic is tunneled through this VPN, so there's no traffic split.
Unfortunately the bandwith when I'm using this is really bad, even when I'm in a 5G mobile network. I have a 50 Mbit fiber cable connection so this shouldn’t cause any problems.

While researching the problem I found this: https://rickfreyconsulting.com/mikrotik-vpns/ which could be an objective confirmation for my subjective feeling. Since I don't know how the author configured his device for these tests I can't finally confirm that.

In the end I'd like to use an IPsec only VPN (without L2TP or others) between iOS and routerOS (on my PPPoE interface) with DDNS for which I found not a single configuration online. On my old Fritzbox router this was easily applicable. A traffic split (using internet with real mobile connection and accessing the home LAN via VPN) would also be an acceptable solution but not the preferred one.

I'm using

- iPhone 13 with iOS 16.3
- hAP ac2 with routerOS 6.49

Can please someone help me here?